# Does call.dispatch make `origin` pay the fees to the network?

Tags: weight, fee

I'm writing a hook for a pallet, this hook pop `Call` out of storage and execute them on behalf of a specified user through `call.dispatch(origin)`.

My question is:
Will `dispatch` will make `origin` pay the fees associated with this `Call`?
If yes is that true both in a the context of a `hook` and in the context of a regular user triggered call causing a `call.dispatch` to be issued? Who pay for what if the `origin` of the dispatched call is different from the origin of the original call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will dispatch will make origin pay the fees associated with this Call?

No, only the signer of a transaction will pay fees for it (although there are some PRs in Substrate to make that a bit more flexible, so this answer may change).

When executing a transaction, it goes through a few phases: pre-dispatch, dispatch, and post-dispatch. The fee for the given length/weight is taken in the pre-dispatch phase, and it won't even dispatch if the account cannot pay the fees. Then dispatch happens, and any fee refund/change, if there is some, would happen in post-dispatch. So, `dispatch` assumes that whatever conditions for dispatch (e.g. a fee, or scheduling by referendum) have already taken place.

Comment: Can you link the PRs that may change this in the future please ?

Comment: So I have a problem here ! How can I make so that `origin` pay for the call dispatched in it's name in a hook ?

Comment: Or in another signed transaction ?
Using the `pre_dispatch` function from the `SignedExtension` trait maybe ?

Comment: Seems like yes, by adding 
`type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees<Runtime>>;` to my pallet config !

Comment: For example: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11524